# How can I change a rowspan attribute within my CGI program?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am writing a CGI script that will process form data, and it should print the name of the input, along with its value, in a table. When I have one or more values with the same name, the name should span rows to accommodate all values that correspond to that name. For example, if I have a name "color" with its values at "red", "green", "blue", then color should span 3 rows in my table. My question is, how would i change the rowspan attribute in my script to accommodate this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict;
use CGI;

print <<HTTP;
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

HTTP

print <<HTML; 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parameters<title>
    <head>

    <body>
     <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">
     <tr>

     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Value</th>

     </tr>

HTML

 my $query = new CGI;

 my($name, $value);

 foreach $name ( $query->param)
 {
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>$name</td>";

    foreach $value($query->param($name))
    {
        print "<td>$value</td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
my $query = new CGI;
my($name, $value);

foreach $name ($query->param) {
    my @values = $query->param($name);
    my $count  = @values;

    print "<tr>";
    print "<td rowspan='$count'>$name</td>";
    print "<td>".shift(@values)."</td>";
    print "</tr>";    

    foreach $value (@values) {   
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>$value</td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }
}
```

BTW, I would suggest you to consider using some template processing system, e.g. [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/).

Comment: Declare variables in the smallest applicable scope. Print rarely and late.